# Can we do sorting on mongodb documents without creating separate indexes for them?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, indexing, mongodb-query

Edit : I am using cosmos apis for mongodb .Earlier I was using mongodb 3.2 and the queries for sorting were working fine. After migrating to 3.6 , the sorting is throwing error. After reading some blogs i found out we need to add index of the field we want to sort on. Also to sort on multiple criteria we should have a composite index in the same order of the sort criteria.
Are these constraints necessary for sorting in mongodb? Is there any other option that i am missing?

Some of the errors are mentioned below :

```
The order by query does not have a corresponding composite index that it can be served from

The index path corresponding to the specified order-by item is excluded.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation of Azure Cosmos DB's API for MongoDB. It looks like Cosmos always requires a supporting index for queries.

Here is a microsoft doc to resolve this error : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/error-codes-solutions